# How do I propose a change to Go formatting?

Tags: go, gofmt

The documentation for [Go's `format` package](https://golang.org/pkg/go/format/) says:

> Note that formatting of Go source code changes over time.

How does that happen? I have a specific minor change that I'd like to run past the community. To be clear, I'm delighted that the community has a standard, and I'm not trying to coopt it. To the contrary, I'd like to know what the sanctioned means is of proposing changes so that they can be considered.

For the curious, what I'd like to propose is this:

```
// Great is a really great function.
func Great(
    anArg      int,    // This explains anArg
    anotherArg string, // This explains anotherArg
) (err error) {
...
```

as opposed to this:

```
// Great is a really great function.
func Great(
    anArg int, // This explains anArg
    anotherArg string, // This explains anotherArg
) (err error) {
...
```

It seems to me that that would be more consistent with:

```
var (
    aVar       = 12          // This explains aVar
    anotherVar = "something" // This explains anotherVar
)
```

or

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    FieldName string
    Value     int
}

var aStructList = []*SomeStruct {
    {
        FieldName: "SomeName", // Comment for FieldName
        Value:     12,         // Comment for Value
    },
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: Though I doubt it will happen. Because the arguments should be explained in the godoc of the function in question.